# Help me undo (accidental)namespace rename in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, namespaces, rename

I did a bad thing, and I need help undoing it, because I don't know where to make the correction and don't want to further mess things up.

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 solution in VS 2010 with three projects.

In one of the projects, I have three folders, each with several files in them.

I realized that I mistakenly created a file in the wrong folder, so I dragged it into the correct folder.

After I did this, I renamed the namespace by typing in the right one, referencing the folder I just moved it into.

When I did that, the magic cursor, or whatever it's called, appeared under the new text I just typed in...so I hovered. It asked me if I wanted to rename from the old value to the new one I just typed in. So, I click yes.

I think a number of you already know what that means, but I hadn't a clue. Yes, I'm new at this. :)

All using statements in my solution referencing the original folder have been renamed in the process. The original folder is no longer available in any using statements I try to add.

Also of note, I had no clue what was doing this and thought my solution was corrupt or something, so I cleaned, and built, and rebuilt, and rebooted...so undo isn't an option.

What are my options for getting back to "normal" in my solution?
Thanks!

**UPDATE, PROBLEM SOLVED:**

All I had to do was rename the bad folder so I could create a new folder in the project with the bad folder's original name. I then moved the files from the bad folder into the new folder and corrected their namespaces.

Trashed the old folder. 
Updated using statements.
Built the solution. 
All is well.

I was afraid the rename went a lot deeper than it did. I'm not certain why this worked, but thank god it did.

Thanks to all who replied. I'll be exploring SVN this evening!

Comment: Any chance your project is under source control (SVN, TFS, etc.)?

Comment: ugh, no. That's on my long list of things to learn. Though this is certainly reason to explore it now, eh.

Comment: Could you rename the namespace to the original and refactor with the 'magic cursor'?  then go back and rename ONLY the new one in the new folder?

Comment: You should put learning a source control provider like TFS, subversion, or git at the top of your list. I've used them all, and for somebody just learning the field, I recommend starting with subversion, because it consistently works the way you expect it to work (git is a little more advanced and tfs has more 'gotchas' than subversion). Check out [the free svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), [tortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and [visual svn server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/) for a SUPER easy set-up on your windows box.

Comment: +1 (or, rather, +Infinity) for suggestions to learn source control and a further +1 for git or other distributed source control systems. Source control is _absolutely essential_ for _any_ nontrivial coding project, and I cannot count the number of times I have been saved by it. Drop everything you've got planned for the weekend and spend it learning a source control system. (My personal recommendation is git or mercurial (the latter is easier) - neither of these require a central server at your workplace; you can have it all on your own machine.)

Answer (score 0):

for example, you have tow folders named: `Views` and `ViewModels` in your project that named `MyMvcProject`; your namespaces will be `MyMvcProject.Views` and `MyMvcProject.ViewModels`;
and you rename the `MyMvcProject.Views` to `MyMvcProject.ViewModels`;
to undo, first exclude the folder named `ViewModels` - right-click on it, and select `Exclude From Project`; now open the `find and replace` window - Ctrl + f - select `Quick Replace` tab, in `Find what` textbox type `.ViewModels` and in `Replace with` textbox type `.Views`; set `Look in` to `Current Project` and click `Replace All`;
now must all `ViewModels` in project - not old viewmodels, because you exclude the `ViewModels` folder from project - be replaced with `Views`; now, include the excluded folder (`ViewModels`) and rebuild the project; if you got an error about namespace of any type, insert this using statement:

```
using MyMvcProject.Views;
```

regards.